# How to read an Excel file from a network drive?

Tags: c#, file, network-drive

I have a dotnet 2.0 C#/web application.

I am able to manually go into a network drive and get a template from that. But through my application, when I try to access this file..it says "access denied".

What to do with this ? Please help

EDIT: Will following work ?

a)Set password for "IUSR_WEBSERVER"
b)And adding below line to webconfig will solve

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="IUSR_WEBSERVER" password="password" /> </system.web>
```

If it work, that means, we need to change IIS config..right. Is there anyother way.

Comment: more details please, this is not answerable in its current state

Answer (score 2):

Are you running your web application as a user that has access to this location? By default, IIS (that which hosts websites in Windows) runs under a restricted account. You could change this to a domain account that has access by changing the application pool settings.

**EDIT** For IIS 5 (Windows XP), there is no concept of application pools. [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/192089/how-to-change-the-user-iis-5-service-runs-on) will help you change your user.

Comment: My application is in my desktop...And it uses the local iis.

Comment: @Anish: If you go to the settings for the application pool for this site, you can change the user under which this will run. Depending on the OS (and therefore the version of IIS, where to go will be different.

Comment: Do you mean a)Set password for "IUSR_WEBSERVER" ?                  b)And adding below line to webconfig will solve ? "<identity impersonate="true" userName="IUSR_WEBSERVER" password="password" /> </system.web>"

Comment: @Anish: No, because IUSR_WEBSERVER is a user local to your machine (which will therefore not have permissions to the share location. I believe you could do impersonation that way (but I have not done so) and use your username and password, but I usually run the entire application pool as the privileged user. Which OS are you running?

Comment: I mean to set the "IUSR_WEBSERVER" of IIS in Test/QA/Prod webserver . OS are I'm running - Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

Using IIS Manager...

1) Create a new application pool and set the Identity to run as you.

2) Go to the properties of your web site and set the application pool to the application pool you just created.